# Google Drive API does not allow to post file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am getting the following error when trying to upload files.   How can i get this number increased?

```
POST https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json

{"title":"4394480","mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder","labels":{"restricted":false},"params":{"fields":"items(id)","quotaUser":"U1VQRVI="},"parents":[{"id":"0B_driE4U__5YWlhvd3VGRm5famc"}]}

Response 403
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "numChildrenInNonRootLimitExceeded",
"message": "The limit for this folder's number of children (files and folders) has been exceeded."
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "The limit for this folder's number of children (files and folders) has been exceeded."
}
}

Error message code:

"numChildrenInNonRootLimitExceeded"
```

Comment: SO Is not Google support,  we cant increase your limit for anything.  Nor is it a good idea to post your email address publicly.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the google drive errors page [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors)

[image]

You will see that the problem is that your directory simply has to many files in it you can not add more.  This is a hard limit from within google drive and nothing that can be changed [Google drive limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490100#limits)

create another directory and upload to that.